# 6 core server vs 10 core server processor, not different in execution of a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, pm2

I have a dedicated server with 6 cores each with 2.5GHz of processing power.

I ran a test on `Node.js` 18 and `pm2` to check the speed of processing like this:

```js
function summBrute(k) {
    const arr = [75, 283, 361, 168, 23, 489, 421, 95, 72, 380, 384, 470, 235, 465, 276, 26, 364, 416, 373, 184, 211, 239, 485, 18, 19, 252, 447, 6, 291, 324, 497, 352,
    458, 201, 238, 116, 333, 163, 207, 417, 340, 431, 5, 269, 258, 178, 182, 295, 257, 434, 37, 372, 154, 223, 313, 80, 71, 229, 379, 181, 396, 281, 491, 58, 254,
    359, 79, 175, 143, 214, 217, 148, 393, 246, 34, 166, 251, 381, 413, 180, 338,
    442, 494, 378, 123, 118, 395, 446, 459, 472, 457, 51, 127, 351, 389, 157, 260,
    370, 405, 346
    ];
    let sum;
    for(let i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        sum += arr.reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + a, 0);
    }
    return sum;
}

setInterval(() => {
    var t0 = performance.now();
    summBrute(200000);
    var t1 = performance.now();
    console.log("Took Time:: " + (t1 - t0) + " milli");
}, 1000);
```

It executes average 70 milliseconds.

The issue is when I use the same function to test the speed of execution in the same server with 10 cores it didn't change the execution time.

4 cores more but still 70 milliseconds execution time???

How could it be possible?

Comment: Your Node process uses one core.

Comment: This is not how performance benchmarking is done, create a thread pool and give some task to that thread pool, and assign these tasks to the pool. 

There are lot of thinks to consider such as logical cores, number of threads, are you creating processors or thread etc etc

Comment: So having 1 core and 10 cores doesn't affect the speed of Nodejs ???

Comment: @RaolmAX - It doesn't affect the speed of your JavaScript code in a single Node.js process, no.

Comment: So in a 10 core machine 9 are useless using node.js ???

Comment: @RaolmAX It depends on what you mean by useless. If you don't use it it's useless. However if you use clustering or you're running multiple services then they're not useless. For network servers (not just for node.js) what matters just as much as number of cores is number of PCIe channels and what's using those channels. A large EPYC with lots of SSDs will still have higher performance running certain types of node servers compared to a desktop Ryzen CPU even though node uses only one core because node can wait for all those I/O in parallel - it is PCIe, not CPU core, that process I/O

Comment: @RaolmAX Any code that doesn't take advantage of multiple cores will run at the same speed *(all other things being equal)*. If you took the code above and translated it to C it also wouldn't run any faster because there's nothing parallel in the code. You might be able to run it through a compiler that can auto-detect parallelism, or you can explicitly parallelize the code. In Node you could use service workers.

Answer (score 0):

By default, your JavaScript code running in Node.js only runs on one thread¹ and therefore one core at a time, regardless of how many cores your system has. (There's a little bit about this in the Node.js docs [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick).) To take advantage of multiple cores, you'd need to use [worker threads](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v20.x/docs/api/worker_threads.html) and/or [child processes](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v20.x/docs/api/child_process.html) (or, I suppose, multiple Node.js processes — e.g., clustering).

¹ *(though Node.js itself may use a couple of others for housekeeping)*

Comment: So in a 10 core machine 9 are useless using node.js ???

Comment: @RaolmAX - Of course not. But to make *use* of them, you have to *"...use worker threads and/or child processes (or, I suppose, multiple Node.js processes -- e.g., clustering)."*